# auto move focus to next cell datagridview

Tags: .net, winforms, datagridview, focus, cell

I have a datagridview(DGV) in whic i want the first cell of the row to be serial number, so i put up this code.

```
  Private Sub dgvStudents_RowEnter(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles DGVStudents.RowEnter
        Dim RowIndex As Integer = e.RowIndex
        Debug.Print(RowIndex.ToString)
        With DGVStudents
            .Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(0).Value = e.RowIndex + 1
            If .Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(0).Selected = True Then
                .Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(0).Selected = False
                .Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(1).Selected = True
            End If
        End With
        DGVStudents.AutoResizeColumns(DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.AllCells)
    End Sub
```

The main aim is on entering a new row, number the first cell and move focus to the next. putting it in edit mode, but i can seem to get it to work. any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you are actually in the edit mode of the first cell, Maybe you could push this into the `CellEnter` event and in case its the first cell use SendKeys.Send("{TAB}") to move you to the next cell. Also if the value is not going to be changed by the user set the first column as `ReadOnly` too.

You can also try by setting the `CurrentCell` property of the `DataGridView` something of this sort

```
datagridview1.CurrentCell = Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(1);
```

Comment: thanks for responding, but using sendkeys is not encouraged as it can have different effect on different os

Comment: Ok then i would recommend you to try setting the `CurrentCell` property of the `datagridview`

Comment: i get an error now `operation not valid because it results in a reenterent call to the setCurrentCellAddressCore function`